# Пример рабочего сервера на Node JS

Tags: node.js

Нужен пример простейшего проекта, реализующего сервер на node JS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js
там просто исчерпывающее количество ссылок на информацию о ноде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res)=>{

// 1. Tell the browser everything is OK (Status code 200), and the data is in plain text.
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
});

// 2. Send the announced text (the body of the page)
res.end('Hello, World!\n');

}).listen(1337);
```

А вот текст по первой ссылке, которая отвечает на вопрос,  проще некуда, мне кажется.